# How to upload an image to use in issue comments via Github API

Tags: ios, api, github

I'm currently working with Github API to make an iOS github client app. 
I'd like to implement the feature of creating issues with images. My question is how to upload an image for issue comments via API. We're able to upload the image by drag-and-drop via browser in github.com like image below: 
[image: image_upload_in_browser]

I'd like to use this `https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/~~~.PNG`.
Any way to upload to https://cloud.githubusercontent.com via API or something?

Answer (score 6):

By the Feb 2020 there are still no official solution to upload files via API to be used in the github issues.

Simple solution is to use a repository branch (you can name it `assets`). You can link to them from the github issues easily, just use raw link with last commit SHA:

```
https://github.com/ORG/REPO/raw/LAST_SHA/PATH
```

This kind of link will be rendered in the issues body always correctly.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I'm using is to push the images to the repository instead, and use a relative link in the issue.

You can create an orphan branch just for images and push it to a ref outside of `refs/heads`, this way this ref is not cloned in a normal clone (you would need `git clone --mirror`).

It would look something like this (proof-of-concept):

```sh
git checkout --orphan images
git rm -rf *
# copy your images to the repo
git add <your images>
git commit -m "add images"
git push origin HEAD:refs/images/image-ref
git log --format=%H
# note the hash
```

and then in the issue, use a [relative link](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#images) using the commit hash from above:

```markdown
![alt text](../blob/<HASH HERE>/path/to/your/image.png?raw=true)
```

Comment: Annoyingly a URL like `https://github.com/user/repo/blob/refs/images/image-ref` doesn't seem to work on github, but using the hash from `git rev-parse HEAD` does work as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Ever I also try to find one way to make it.But there is not any available method to do it. I'm doing some extra test to find that you can observe the drag-and-drop action in your devtool-network panel.

I find that https://github.com/upload/assets/21842410 be requested with PUT method, and its response is {"id":21842410,"name":"-2.png","size":1261,"content_type":"image/png","href":"https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3518853/21842410/7c3f6812-d79b-11e6-8209-e49b44aaa883.png","original_name":null}

I've not finished my test, if this inspires you and you have time to implement any demo, please tell me your result. :)

Comment: thank you for sharing your experience. I requested the same url  https://github.com/upload/assets/1234567 with PUT method, but response was 432 error. I don't think I can find the way to be authenticated. I hope github will implement for us

Comment: OK, the 432 error as you don't supply enough auth data in the http request, to make it work costs lots of time, and this is not official way to solve it. It's not recommended, but if official never release one, this is only way.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. Your only chance is to upload your image to your own s3 bucket or similar and link that in the comment/issue. I think github will pick up those and cache them for better user experienceon github.com